# Multiline text in dynamicaly changed TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textblock, twitch

Hi so i am trying to push a twitch chat into a TextBlock and it worked fine just using the mvvm with the textblock but now i want to actualy color the username and not sure how to make this multiline because the way i have it now it just replaces the previous message so i would need help to move forward. thanks!\

Xaml:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="Gainsboro" FontSize="14" Text="" Margin="5,5,5,5">
            <Run Text="{Binding Username, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="{Binding UsernameColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Run Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneWay}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Event:

```
private void Client_OnMessageReceived(object sender, OnMessageReceivedArgs e)
        {
            Username = $"{e.ChatMessage.DisplayName}:";
            Message = e.ChatMessage.Message;
            UsernameColor = e.ChatMessage.ColorHex;
        }
```

so the issue is i want it to be multiline and not replace the Runs everytime a message comes thru.

Comment: @do you want to create a new `<Textblock>` for each message?

Comment: @dbvega no i would like to just have one textblock

Comment: then the issue is you need to make it multiline? TO solve the multiline change it to `<Run .../>` then `<LineBreak/>` then `<Run .../>`

Comment: What is the reason behind using just one `TextBlock`? This sounds more like a use-case for an items control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are following the wrong approach. You have to see a chat as a collection of messages. You want to display each message individually, as they come in. This shouts to use a `ListBox` where each item represents an individual message:

**ChatMessage.cs**

```
class ChatMessage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string username;
  public string Username
  {
    get => this.username;
    set
    {
      this.username = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string message;
  public string Message
  {
    get => this.message;
    set
    {
      this.message = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string colorValue;
  public string ColorValue
  {
    get => this.colorValue;
    set
    {
      this.colorValue = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<ChatMessage> Messages { get; set; }

  private void Client_OnMessageReceived(object sender, OnMessageReceivedArgs e)
  {
    var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
    { 
      Username = $"{e.ChatMessage.DisplayName}:",
      Message = e.ChatMessage.Message
      UsernameColor = e.ChatMessage.ColorHex
    }
    this.Messages.Add(chatMessage);
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  <Window.DataContext>

  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
           IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ChatMessage}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizonatal">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}" 
                     Foreground="{Binding ColorValue}" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate >
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
</Window>
```

Comment: You are completely right good sir, i looked at it from the wrong angle, thank you times! guess i am out of practice sadly

Comment: I am glad I could help. You can easily style the ListBoxItem to remove the list look. You can set ListBoxItem.IsHitTestVisible to false to disable selection and highlighting. I think it even should be enough to disable hit test on the ListBox instead of the items.